# How to make push notification request to GCM on server side using ruby on rails?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-messaging

I am building an android app, and I tried to figure out the process of using GCM for instant messaging. the client-side android code is understandable from various sources on internet, but I could not find any reference to server side code in Ruby-on-Rails. My server is ruby-on_rails. I got a php version of server code, but i could not implement it in ruby. Here's the php version--

[GCM for android using PHP, Mysql](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

I just need the ruby version of this server side code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an existing Ruby gem for GCM, such as [this one](https://github.com/spacialdb/gcm) or [this one](https://github.com/dondeng/gcm_on_rails).

Comment: @Ranzit: I have no idea. Ask the authors of those gems.